# Append new rows to HTML table being called by MySQL query, and update current column in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Two part question.  Not necessarily asking for any code here, just a direction on how to handle it will suffice.

I've got a table stored in a row in a MySQL table, we'll call it `$row['request']` which when echoed will print a full `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`.

This is all generated by the user when they submit their task, and I really can't change that at the moment.

So let's say the user decides in a few days he wants to update the HTML table that `$row['request']` HTML table by adding some new rows to the bottom.

How will I add these rows before the `</table>` tag at the end of my echoed result?

Here's what I've got for adding a new row: [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UX5M4/).

If this will suffice, how then will I add this new HTML data to the existing field in MySQL?

Should I use something like

```
$query = "UPDATE t1
   SET request = CONCAT(request,'$extra')
   WHERE id = '$id'";
```

I'm confused how I'll append this with the additional `</table>` still being tagged on before I add the new HTML.

I could also just rewrite the entire field, but I'm not quite sure how to grab the entire table as a PHP variable and submit that.  Thanks for the help as always.

Edit: I am storing the `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` information in a single field in my MySQL table.  I know this is annoying, but the table is initially generated by user pasted content from an Excel table to a textarea, and the submit query replaces \n and \t with the table tags.  So when I click Add Row, I need the new `<tr><td></td></tr>` info to be submitted to the UPDATE query as well as the data inside it.  That's my problem.

Comment: I'm confused about the first part of your question.  The jsfiddle seems to be working fine.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough.  When new row is clicked, it keeps the text in the input text box, rather than adding a new row, which I don't want to submit in the mysql update.

Comment: I think I understand even less now...

Comment: In the JsFiddle example, the text is added in a text box.  I'll have to make the JS instead add a new row with just the text when new row is clicked.  <td>Text Here</td> instead of with the input text box.  It's not actually submitting anything though when I click new row, so it can't pass it off as data to the JS.  Then, the second part comes in.  How do I add these new <td>'s to the mysql field?

Comment: I don't see anything that says "new row."  Do you mean "add row?"  And you don't have some kind of submit button for submitting the added rows either.  Do you want it to happen automatically?  If so, when?

Comment: Yes I meant add row.  There will be a save button to submit the information that the user clicks.  The reason I'm not just putting forms at the bottom to submit when save is clicked, is because I don't know how to get them in the mysql database inside the <table> tag.

Comment: If they're inputs, don't they get submitted via `<form>` automatically?  It shouldn't matter if they're in `<table>` tags.

Comment: I need them to be in the <table> tags so the're a part of the table that exists already.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I'm just saying if you surround the whole `<table>` with `<form>` and there are `<input>` in the table, when you submit the form those inputs will still be submitted normally

Comment: I need the new <td> information to be submitted too.

Comment: There is new `<td>` information that is *not* in `<input>`s?  How does it get there?

Comment: "Add Row" creates new `<input>` elements doesn't it?  So what's the problem?  Why wouldn't they submit with the rest of the form?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why I'm not comprehending you, maybe because it's late.  Add Row makes `<td><input/></td>`.  I'm not aware of a way to submit anything in `<form>` other than form elements.  I need these HTML table tags to be submitted in the actual string to MySQL.  Like `$string = "<td><input /></td>";`

P.S. Sorry to those reading this, I don't have enough reputation to move to chat.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `<input>` are inside of anything else (be it `<td>` or whatever) they'll still get submitted

Comment: Let's say the `<input>` tags don't exist right now.  How do I get the `<td>` tags that were generated to be submitted to the query?  I am storing the html table tags in my MySQL row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your comments, I guess you wanna "submit the entire HTML string of new `tr` to MySQL", you can do this:

```
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-row').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  counter++;

  var $tr = $( '.requesttable tr:last' ) // assume new <tr> always the last one
  $tr.find( 'input' ).each( function() {
    $(this.parentNode).html( this.value ) // get rid of <input> tag, only keep value
  })

  $.ajax( {
    url: url, // PHP page that receive data and update MySQL
    data: $tr.get(0).outerHTML, // "<tr><td>value1</td><td>value2</td></tr>"
    type: 'post', // or 'get', depends on your PHP page
    success: function() {
      // if added, append new row
    },
    error: function() {
      // if failed, alert user
    }
  } )
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is pretty much it.  Am I wrong to assume that the new row will be added after the </table> tag that already exists if I just UPDATE MySQL table with this post data?  I could fix it up in PHP, that wouldn't be to big of a deal, but would it be easier to just get all of the HTML data for the table as an UPDATE instead of CONCAT & UPDATE?

Comment: @KevinO'Brien for back-end side, one `UPDATE` is faster than `CONCAT & UPDATE`, especially for large string, but if you want better user experience, you should SYNC data betweetn front-end and back-end when user's done something.

Comment: @KevinO'Brien and you did right, when data's been updated, you should notify user, and updated data should be shown, in your case, the new row should be added to `table`. What matters is how you achieve it, by refreshing page (generate new HTML page) or ajax (like native app).